# How to produce rank in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, analytic-functions, top-n

Need to rank the below by salary, with highest salary having rank 1.

The `RANK` column shown is what I'm after:

```
Empname        sal      address           RANK
----------------------------------------------
Ram            3411     45,east road      2
Anirban        2311     34,west wind      4
Sagor          10000    34,south          1
Manisha        3111     12,d.h road       3
```

Comment: Don't type in all caps and include some line breaks.  You know, the editor shows a preview of what its going to look like...

Answer (score 4):

Oracle10g means you can use analytic/ranking/windowing functions like ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT t.empname,
       t.sal,
       t.address,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.sal DESC) AS RANK
  FROM TABLE t
```

For the pedantic, replace `ROW_NUMBER` with [DENSE_RANK](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php) if you want to see ties get the same rank value:

> If two employees had the same salary, the [RANK](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php) function would return the same rank for both employees. **However, this will cause a gap in the ranks** (ie: non-consecutive ranks). This is quite different from the dense_rank function which generates consecutive rankings.

The old school means of ranking is to use:

```
SELECT t.empname,
       t.sal,
       t.address,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM TABLE x 
         WHERE x.sal <= t.sal) AS RANK
  FROM TABLE t
```

The output will match the DENSE_RANK output -- ties will have the same rank value, while being numbered consecutively.

Comment: You may want to change your answer to use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER().  RANK() returns ties, whereas ROW_NUMBER() arbitrarily orders ties with unique numbers.

Comment: Where's the requirement to handle ties?  Fact is, the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subselect approach will give ties the same rank value.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at rank - samples [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/dense_rank_vs_rank_vs_row_number.html).

Answer (score 1):

I often refer to this detailed, informative yet quick link [Analytical Functions](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) for the analytical functions.